# Issue in receiving and sending Firebase OTP in Android

Tags: android, firebase, one-time-password

When I try to send an OTP, it is going directly to the `onVerificationComplete()`
and the app crashes on where we get the OTP code from credentials. Because the app didn't invoke `onSendVerificationCode()`.

I am using OTP for Android app. but I am facing this issue only when I use Android Pie. it's working well in KitKat and lollipop.

Comment: Please provide code snippet, of both sending and receiving so that the developers can help you. Also tell where are you using the code web or app (platform) ? any relevant versions. Also try to make the title more informative naming the technology in there.

Comment: I am using this in android app.
but I am facing this issue only when I uses Android Pie.
it's working well in KitKat and lollipop

Comment: Please provide the error logcat.